# jquery clickable row function returning call stack exceeded error

Tags: jquery

I'm writing an admin app with lots of tables, with buttons in each row (edit, delete). Usually, the buttons are s but sometimes they are s with button styling. In order to make the app easier to use, I have written the following function to make clicking anywhere in the TR trigger a click on the first button or an in the row.

```
$('.click-rows tr').not(".non-clickable-row").click(function() {
    $(this).find("a, button").first().click();
});
```

About 80% of the time it works as designed, but sometimes it causes a "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded." in the developer console (Safari). There doesn't seem to be any consistency with it - I've had the problem on a page with 5  buttons in each row, and now on a different page with a single  in each row. On the most complex page with mix of  and  it works perfectly. I'm suspecting some issue with the total number of buttons on the screen, but I'm having this problem with a table to 18 rows, each with only a single button, so that shouldn't exhaust resources.

Can anyone see a condition that would cause this function to go into an endless loop? If no a or button is found shouldn't it just do nothing?

Example table row:

```
<tbody class="click-rows">
<tr>
    <td>Test Record</td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs edit-button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-id="3" data-original-title="Edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I don't think it's due to your jquery code. Must be something else. Any other script maybe triggering once button is clicked?

Comment: I haven't ruled that out, but one of the pages that causes troubles only has 3 <a> tags in the row, so no other script is called. I am looking at one of the pages with a <button> that has an onclick action that opens a modal now; i'll let you know if I find anything.

Comment: Actually it is your code indeed sorry please see my answer with example code that will work and prevent the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your original code is basically due to the fact that when you click the `<tr>` element with the mouse it actually triggers the function correctly, but after that you trigger an click event on the button that is also inside the `<tr>` itself, so it will create the loop. You can filter this and check if the button clicked is NOT the button itself and execute the trigger.

If you would do a test, and console log the output of the nodeName, you will notice that it actually returns `TD` as a value because you actually click on the `<td>` element.

`e.target.nodeName` basically captures the name of the element.

> The target event property returns the element that triggered the event.

A clear example can be found here: [target Event Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_event_target)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  
  $(document).on('click', '.click-rows tr', function(e) {
    if( e.target.nodeName!='BUTTON' ) {
     $(this).find('button').trigger('click');
    }  
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
   console.log('button clicked!');
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody class="click-rows">
    <tr>
      <td>Test Record</td>
      <td>
        <button>button</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Interesting. This is the cause... It was so hard to find because when I have a <button>, the onClick action has a e.stopPropagation(); in it which also solves this problem and when it's an <a> it seems like a race between the browser getting to the href and js collapsing. An interesting example of a click bubbling up. Thanks.

Comment: PS: no need to be sorry when you are right! I knew there was something wrong, it was just a case of finding it!